# TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION and TYPE_GRAVITY not working

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm working on a project where among other things, I'm trying to obtain the accelerometer data without the gravity components. However, I don't seem to be able to get updates from the virtual sensors: "linear acceleration" and "gravity". Here's the code:

```
    public class SensorModule implements SensorEventListener{

    (...)

    public SensorModule(Context context){

        this.context = context;
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorAccelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorMagneticField = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        sensorLinearAccel = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
        sensorGravity = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {}

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        switch(event.sensor.getType()){
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            ((SensorActivity)context).accelX.setText("" + event.values[0]);
            ((SensorActivity)context).accelY.setText("" + event.values[1]);
            ((SensorActivity)context).accelZ.setText("" + event.values[2]);
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            ((SensorActivity)context).magneX.setText("" + event.values[0]);
            ((SensorActivity)context).magneY.setText("" + event.values[1]);
            ((SensorActivity)context).magneZ.setText("" + event.values[2]);
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION:
            ((SensorActivity)context).linearX.setText("" + event.values[0]);
            ((SensorActivity)context).linearY.setText("" + event.values[1]);
            ((SensorActivity)context).linearZ.setText("" + event.values[2]);
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY:
            ((SensorActivity)context).gravityX.setText("" + event.values[0]);
            ((SensorActivity)context).gravityY.setText("" + event.values[1]);
            ((SensorActivity)context).gravityZ.setText("" + event.values[2]);
        }
    }

    public void registerListeners(){
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorMagneticField, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorLinearAccel, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorGravity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    public void unregisterListeners(){
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, sensorAccelerometer);
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, sensorMagneticField);
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, sensorLinearAccel);
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, sensorGravity);
    }
```

I register the listeners onResume() and unregister onPause() in the activity. I can get updates from the accelerometer and magnetometer just fine, but the TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION and TYPE_GRAVITY are not producing any updates. I know my device has these virtual sensors from getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL). Also when I call getDefaultSensor(...) it returns non null for every one of these 4 sensors. I toasted each case inside the onSensorChanged() method individually, but the linear and gravity ones never show up, which means these updates are not being produced. I've also tried a larger delay (SENSOR_DELAY_UI) to give it more time, but still no dice. I'm testing on a Nexus 5 running Lollipop 5.0.1 (API 21). Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OK**, by applying the first rule of engineering and general common sense the problem was solved :) Just turned it off and on again, and now it automagically works. This is a bit troubling though, because it means I have no way of knowing if the sensors are working properly other than using a timeout thread to verify periodic updates.